# Delphi 2007 WSDL Import, setting SOAP header information

Tags: delphi, wsdl, soapheader

Importing WDSL in Delphi 2007 works fine, but generates a Cannot Unwrap warning (code snippet 1, below [like another question already logged on StackOverFlow]).

However, it is how we set the headers `(REQUESTOR:pIn, REQUEST_USER:pIn, REQUEST_PASSWORD:pIn)` that is unclear from the generated code. Looking elsewhere on the Net, we also tried the command line utilitiy `WDSLImp`, which allowed us to use switches to, for example, unwrap literals. No good.

Snippet 2 shows the initialization stuff, which we have variously tried substituting real values for the three header parameters. The end result should appear over the interface like this snippet 3.

All help very much appreciated.

Snippet 1:

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// Namespace : http//www.sx3.com/GET_SERVICE_STATUS.wsdl
// soapAction: https//xxx.org.uk:23105/communication/gateway
// transport : http//schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
// style     : document
// binding   : UpdGetServiceStatusBinding
// service   : UpdGetServiceStatusService
// port      : UpdGetServiceStatusPort
// URL       : http//machine:port/communication/UpdGetServiceStatus
// ************************************************************************ //
UpdGetServiceStatusPort = interface(IInvokable)
['{CB3F81D1-5267-4897-C244-288E348AA34E}']

// Cannot unwrap: 
//     - Input element wrapper name does not match operation's name
//     - More than one strictly out element was found
// Headers: REQUESTOR:pIn, REQUEST_USER:pIn, REQUEST_PASSWORD:pIn
function  UpdGetServiceStatus(const parameters: GetServiceStatusRequest): GET_SERVICE_STATUS; stdcall;
end;

function GetUpdGetServiceStatusPort(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): UpdGetServiceStatusPort;


implementation
  uses SysUtils;

function GetUpdGetServiceStatusPort(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): UpdGetServiceStatusPort;
const
  defWSDL = 'get_service_status_net.wsdl';
  defURL  = 'http//machine:port/communication/UpdGetServiceStatus';
  defSvc  = 'UpdGetServiceStatusService';
  defPrt  = 'UpdGetServiceStatusPort';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as UpdGetServiceStatusPort);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Snippet 2:

```
initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(UpdGetServiceStatusPort), 'http//www.sx3.com/GET_SERVICE_STATUS.wsdl', 'utf-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(UpdGetServiceStatusPort), 'https//xxx.org.uk:23105/communication/gateway');
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(UpdGetServiceStatusPort), ioDocument);
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(UpdGetServiceStatusPort), ioLiteral);
  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(UpdGetServiceStatusPort), REQUESTOR, 'REQUESTOR', 'http//www.yyy.com/IntegratorCoreTypes');
  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(UpdGetServiceStatusPort), REQUEST_USER, 'REQUEST_USER', 'http//www.yyy.com/IntegratorCoreTypes');
  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(UpdGetServiceStatusPort), REQUEST_PASSWORD, 'REQUEST_PASSWORD', 'http//www.yyy.com/IntegratorCoreTypes');
  InvRegistry.RegisterExternalParamName(TypeInfo(UpdGetServiceStatusPort), 'UpdGetServiceStatus', 'parameters1', 'parameters');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(APIMessagesType), 'http//www.sx3.com/UpdGetServiceStatusResponse', 'APIMessagesType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(GET_SERVICE_STATUS, 'http//www.sx3.com/UpdGetServiceStatusResponse', 'GET_SERVICE_STATUS');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(GET_SERVICE_STATUS, [xoLiteralParam]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(GetServiceStatusRequestType, 'http//www.sx3.com/GET_SERVICE_STATUS', 'GetServiceStatusRequestType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(GetServiceStatusRequestType, [xoLiteralParam]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(GetServiceStatusRequest, 'http//www.sx3.com/GET_SERVICE_STATUS', 'GetServiceStatusRequest');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(char4000), 'http://www.sx3.com/houCommonTypes', 'char4000');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(GetServiceStatusType, 'http//www.sx3.com/UpdGetServiceStatusResponse', 'GetServiceStatusType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(char25), 'http//www.sx3.com/houCommonTypes', 'char25');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(APIMessageType, 'http//www.sx3.com/UpdGetServiceStatusResponse', 'APIMessageType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(char30), 'http//www.sx3.com/houCommonTypes', 'char30');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(char7), 'http//www.sx3.com/houCommonTypes', 'char7');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(MESSAGEType, 'http//www.sx3.com/sx3returnedmessages', 'MESSAGEType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterExternalPropName(TypeInfo(MESSAGEType), 'TYPE_', 'TYPE');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(int15), 'http//www.sx3.com/houCommonTypes', 'int15');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(GetServiceStatusResponseType, 'http//www.sx3.com/UpdGetServiceStatusResponse', 'GetServiceStatusResponseType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(RETURNED_MESSAGESType), 'http//www.sx3.com/sx3returnedmessages', 'RETURNED_MESSAGESType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(MESSAGE_RETURN_INFO, 'http//www.sx3.com/sx3returnedmessages', 'MESSAGE_RETURN_INFO');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(MESSAGE_RETURN_INFO2, 'http//www.sx3.com/sx3returnedmessages', 'MESSAGE_RETURN_INFO2', 'MESSAGE_RETURN_INFO');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(REQUESTOR, 'http//www.yyy.com/IntegratorCoreTypes', 'REQUESTOR');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(REQUESTOR, [xoSimpleTypeWrapper]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(REQUEST_USER, 'http//www.yyy.com/IntegratorCoreTypes', 'REQUEST_USER');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(REQUEST_USER, [xoSimpleTypeWrapper]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(REQUEST_PASSWORD, 'http//www.yyy.com/IntegratorCoreTypes', 'REQUEST_PASSWORD');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(REQUEST_PASSWORD, [xoSimpleTypeWrapper]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(APIMessage, 'http//www.sx3.com/UpdGetServiceStatusResponse', 'APIMessage');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(MESSAGE_, 'http//www.sx3.com/sx3returnedmessages', 'MESSAGE_', 'MESSAGE');
```

Snippet 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http//schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xs="http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:ig="http//www.yyy.com/IntegratorCoreTypes" 
xmlns:ng1="http//www.sx3.com/GET_WORKS_ORDERS_LIST">
  <soap:Header>
    <ig:REQUESTOR>REALREQUESTOR</ig:REQUESTOR>
    <ig:REQUEST_USER>REALREQUEST_USER</ig:REQUEST_USER>
    <ig:REQUEST_PASSWORD>realpassword</ig:REQUEST_PASSWORD>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ng1:WorksOrdersListRequest/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```